# Synchronization of the standard output in Clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure

I have a multithreaded application written in Clojure. There is a problem of making a text in the console display correctly when multiple threads write to STDOUT. How can I do this correctly in Clojure, so the lines won't look interlaced? I think this would involve some kind of separate IO agent, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think this would involve some kind of separate IO agent

Yes, that should work. Create an agent `(def printer (agent nil))` and call it with the appropriate `print` statement, e.g, `(send printer #(println msg))`. The messages are put in a queue and are executed (asynchronously) one at a time.

For logging purposes you could also look at [`tools.logging`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging) which uses agents under the hood.

Comment: This works, except I have to send to agent a print job through an another function proxy. Sending println directly to agent won't work for some reasons.

Comment: In [this article](http://clojure.org/agents) on Clojure's website, it says:


"Actions dispatched to an agent from another **single agent or thread** will occur in the order they were sent, **potentially interleaved** with actions dispatched to the same agent **from other sources**."


Does this mean there still might be problems when "**multiple threads** write to STDOUT"?